# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'shift' of null

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, requirejs

I'm only getting this message in Chrome. Firefox works just fine. I've been debugging trying to find at what point this error is happening and can't seem to nail it down. The exact message is, "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'shift' of null" from all.js:57.

Also, I'll note a few other things that may help you help me:

- I'm loading the SDK as a requirejs module. I've tried loading it the "normal way" as well but the result is the same.
- It's not happening locally, only on our staging server. This makes me think it has something to do latency during the SDK load.
- It's only happening in Chrome. Firefox works as well as Safari. The only difference in Safari is that I see a similar error stating that it's a type issue. The message there is "'null' is not an object (evaluating 'queue.shift`)" @ debug.js:2712 but it doesn't break the app.

Any help and/or insight here would be great.

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution for this issue?   I randomly get this same error in Chrome.

Comment: At the very least this question needs to show how you actually load the Facebook code. At the moment, you've got a bunch of answers that are guesses.

Answer (score 1):

Rewriting calling the SDK script helped me. It needs to be called as it's explained [on facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/).

Firstly I tried to append a script to head element simply with id='fasebook-jssdk', but an error with method 'shift' occurred. Then I rewrote it as it's recommended by facebook, without FB.init(). But the error went on occurring until I added FB.init() call. Now it works ok.

Trying to solve it, I found a debug version of 'all.js' [file](http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all/debug.js), where I found that error occurs in the following code:

```
function flush() {
  if (!queue) {
    return;
  }

  var fn;
  while (fn = queue.shift()) {
    fn();
  }
  queue = null;
}
```

where queue is an array of functions. I have no idea about the reason, but now, when the script goes ok, I don't really need to have. Maybe somebody more scrupulous than me will find out.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. This solved if for me. These were the symptoms:

1. No issues on localhost
2. On servers (Amazon S3) occasionally get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'shift' of null"

Solution:

I had messed up the order of the include of the Facebook SDK and the handler of the fbAsyncInit. You should include the SDK after you include the script for handling the loading of the SDK. Otherwise the SDK could load before the handler for it's load event has been registered.

```
<script src="Your script with fbAsyncInit here"> </script>
   <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=200817623450198";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
      }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I can help much, but I have the same issue which might aid in closing in on the problem.

Loading JS likeso:

```
<script src='//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js'></script>
```

> "It's not happening locally, only on our staging server. This makes me
>   think it has something to do latency during the SDK load."

I tend to agree. The error seems to occur sporadically only. In addition, I get the occasional CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE undefined error. Seems all to be related to connectivity.

Answer (score 0):

These [Facebook Instructions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) explain a different way to call the SDK and this worked for me. I haven't tested it yet, but I think the channel file will let you test this locally, which is super sweet.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    // init the FB JS SDK
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID', // App ID from the App Dashboard
      channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File for x-domain communication
      status     : true, // check the login status upon init?
      cookie     : true, // set sessions cookies to allow your server to access the session?
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML tags on this page?
    });

    // Additional initialization code such as adding Event Listeners goes here

  };

  // Load the SDK's source Asynchronously
  // Note that the debug version is being actively developed and might 
  // contain some type checks that are overly strict. 
  // Please report such bugs using the bugs tool.
  (function(d, debug){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all" + (debug ? "/debug" : "") + ".js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document, /*debug*/ false));
</script>
```